# How to color an area at impulse response plot in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot, digital

I plotted the impulse response of a digital system with the impz(b,a) command and I want to color on the plot the area between (-std,std). I have already added the lines that show -std and std values but I dont know how to do it. Can you help me? Can it be done graphically?

Comment: Just use `hold on` and plot the area in the wanted range in a different color...

Comment: It can't be done graphically? And if not, how can I use the hold on command as I have not created my plot with plot command but with impz(b,a)? Thanks

Comment: Do you want to give the line a different color in that area (like @EitanT suggested), or do you want to use a background color?

Comment: I want to change the background color between the 2 lines..

Comment: You can use `fill`: http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/fill.html

Comment: It's too complicated for me to use fill to a plot generated from impz. I dont know if it's even possible...

Comment: @iiirxs At first I didn't understand your original question; you should rephrase it so that it is clear that you want to change the background. Anyway, maybe you can use the syntax `[h, t] = impz(b, a)` to store the impulse response data in a variable rather than plotting it with `impz`, and then use `fill` with the extracted data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As EitanT suggested above:

```
[h, t] = impz(b, a);
figure()
plot(t,h)
hold on
ind=[find(t==-std):find(t==std)]
fill(t(ind),h(ind))
```